# How do I write Nested Generics in Kotlin's Sealed Classes

Tags: kotlin, generics, nested-generics

I'm trying to come up with a data model that allows me to do the following:

- Define a type of `Task` and change its `Status`
- This `Status` can be either `InProgress` or `Completed`
- In the case of a completed `Status`, I want to be able to add data, that is specific to the `Task` that was completed.

Initially, I came up with this data model:

```
sealed class Task<R : TaskResult> {
    
    abstract val status: TaskStatus<R>

    data class A(
        val data: String,
        override val status: TaskStatus<NoResult>,
    ) : Task<NoResult>()

    data class B(
        val data: String,
        override val status: TaskStatus<TaskBResult>,
    ) : Task<TaskBResult>()
}

sealed class TaskStatus<R : TaskResult> {
    object InProgress : TaskStatus<NoResult>()
    data class Completed<R : TaskResult>(val result: R) : TaskStatus<R>()
}

sealed class TaskResult {
    object NoResult : TaskResult()
    data class TaskBResult(val resultData: String) : TaskResult()
}
```

Here you have `Task.A` and `Task.B`, where:

- A completed `Task.A` only accepts `NoResult`
- A completed `Task.B` only accepts `TaskBResult`

However, when I run this:

```
fun main() {
    val taskA = Task.A(
        data = "data",
        status = TaskStatus.InProgress
    ).copy(
        status = TaskStatus.Completed(
            result = NoResult
        )
    )

    val taskB = Task.B(
        data = "data",
        status = TaskStatus.InProgress
    ).copy(
        status = TaskStatus.Completed(
            result = TaskBResult(
                resultData = "resultData"
            )
        )
    )
}
```

I get the following compile error for setting the initial status of `Task.B`:

```
status = TaskStatus.InProgress
    Type mismatch.
    Required: TaskStatus<TaskResult.TaskBResult>
    Found: TaskStatus.InProgress
```

Does anyone know how to change the data model so I'm allowed to run this (or a very similar) `main` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work with a very little change: just make `TaskStatus` a covariant generic class and make `InProgress` a `TaskStatus<Nothing>`. This is a typical strategy you can use when you have "special case" objects that represent no state. After this change, your code should compile:

```kotlin
    sealed class Task<R : TaskResult> {

        abstract val status: TaskStatus<R>

        data class A(
            val data: String,
            override val status: TaskStatus<TaskResult.NoResult>,
        ) : Task<TaskResult.NoResult>()

        data class B(
            val data: String,
            override val status: TaskStatus<TaskResult.TaskBResult>,
        ) : Task<TaskResult.TaskBResult>()
    }

    sealed class TaskStatus<out R : TaskResult> {
        object InProgress : TaskStatus<Nothing>()
        data class Completed<R : TaskResult>(val result: R) : TaskStatus<R>()
    }

    sealed class TaskResult {
        object NoResult : TaskResult()
        data class TaskBResult(val resultData: String) : TaskResult()
    }
```

```
fun main() {
    val taskA = Task.A(
        data = "data",
        status = TaskStatus.InProgress
    ).copy(
        status = TaskStatus.Completed(
            result = NoResult
        )
    )

    val taskB = Task.B(
        data = "data",
        status = TaskStatus.InProgress
    ).copy(
        status = TaskStatus.Completed(
            result = TaskBResult(
                resultData = "resultData"
            )
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Any chance you might also have a solution for passing NoResult as a default argument in Completed?

Comment: I don't think it's possible while still preserving the generic parameter. The best way would be to write a parameterless function with the same name in the same scope that just calls the constructor with NoResult. At least that's what I would do.